# How can I find angle between two turtles(agents) in a network in netlogo simulator?

Tags: netlogo, simulator, angle, robotics, agent-based-modeling

In a formation robots are linked with eachother,number of robots in a neighbourhood may vary. If one robot have 5 neighbours how can I find the angle of that one robot with its other neighbour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Following a comment, I replaced the sequence of* <`face` *+ read* `heading`> *with just using* `towards`, *wich I had overlooked as an option. For some reason the comment I am referring to has been deleted quickly so I don't know who gave the suggestion, but I read enough of it from the cell notification)*

In NetLogo it is often possible to use turtles' `heading` to know degrees.

Since your agents are linked, a first thought could be to use `link-heading`, which directly [reports the heading in degrees from *end1* to *end2*](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#link-heading).

However note that this might not be ideal: using `link-heading` will work spotlessly only if you are interested in knowing the heading from *end1* to *end2*, which means:

- If your links are **directed**, it reports the heading from the source to the target;
- If your links are **undirected**, it reports the heading [from the older turtle to the younger turtle](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#links).

If that's something that you are interested in, fine. But it might not be so! For example, if you have undirected links and are interested in knowing the angle from `turtle 1` to `turtle 0`, using `link-heading` will give you the wrong value:

```
to setup
  clear-all

  create-turtles 2 [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color black
   set label who
  ]

  ask turtle 0 [
   create-link-with turtle 1 
  ]
end


to go
  ask link 0 1 [
   show link-heading 
  ]
end
```

[image]

... while we know, by looking at the two turtles' positions, that the degrees from `turtle 1` to `turtle 0` must be in the vicinity of 45.

An approach that better fits all possible cases is to directly look into the `heading` of the turtle you are interested in, regardless of the nature or direction of the link. You can let your reference turtle `face` the target turtle, and then read `heading` of the reference turtle. Or better: you can directly use `towards`, which reports just the same information but without having to make turtles actually change their heading. Copy and run the code below to see how this approach always gives the right answer!

```
to setup
  clear-all

  create-turtles 5 [
   setxy random-xcor random-ycor
   set color black
   set label who
  ]
end


to go
  let reference sort turtles
  foreach reference [
   r ->
   ask r [
     print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
     let targets sort other turtles
     foreach targets [
       t ->
       let direction (towards t)
       type "I am " type self type ". The NetLogo angle between me and " type t type " is " type direction type ", while the normal mathematical angle is " print heading-to-angle direction  
      ]
     print "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    ] 
  ]
end


to-report heading-to-angle [ h ]
  report (90 - h) mod 360
end
```

In your case, the target group (that I have set just as `other turtles` in my brief example above) could be based on the actual links and so be constructed as `(list link-neighbors)` or `sort link-neighbors` (because if you want to use `foreach`, the agentset must be passed as a list - [see here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#foreach)).

**Update**: I actually ended up also making a toy model that represents your case more closely, i.e. with links and using `link-neighbors`. See below:

```
to setup
  clear-all

  create-turtles 100 [
   move-to one-of patches with [not any? turtles-here]
   set color black
   set label who
  ]

  ask n-of 2 turtles [
   create-links-with n-of 5 other turtles 
  ]
end


to go
  let reference-turtles sort turtles with [count my-links > 2]
  foreach reference-turtles [
   r ->
   ask r [
     print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
     let targets sort link-neighbors
     foreach targets [
       t ->
       let direction (towards t)
       type "I am " type self type ". The NetLogo angle between me and " type t type " is " type direction type ", while the normal mathematical angle is " print heading-to-angle direction
      ]
     print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    ] 
  ]
end


to-report heading-to-angle [ h ]
  report (90 - h) mod 360
end
```

Final note: you surely noticed the `heading-to-angle` procedure, taken directly from the `atan` entry [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#atan). It is a useful way to convert degrees expressed in the NetLogo geometry (where North is 0 and East is 90) to degrees expressed in the usual mathematical way (where North is 90 and East is 0). I don't know what degrees you're interested in, so it's worth to leave this hint here.